# Identify home network

Tags: networking, laptop

Is there a good/recommended way to identify my home network from my laptop. I want to have when I am at home my laptop will automatically sync with my local file server and start services (eg. ssh) that I don't want running when I am not on a trusted network.

Would the best way be to ping where my local server should be, maybe have it identify itself with a gpg/ssh key.

I am running Arch Linux on an HP laptop. Thanks.

Comment: This is phrased as an "opinion" question and so might well get closed. You could look at the wireless SSID. Or DHCP address and domain (particularly if you use a sticky address). Coupled with ping and an SSH probe you'll probably not do better. If you decide on a path and get stuck implementing it that would be a better question for Unix.SE.